# Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS Installed but won't boot Mac Mini 4,1

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, mac-mini

As the title implies, I've managed to "successfully" install Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS on my mid 2010 Mac Mini (4,1).  But upon agreeing to reboot the system after the installation process completed, the machine booted into what looks like a command line that refreshes every 15 (or so) seconds with things that I don't understand.  I've tried hard power cycling and I end up in the same place.

Here's an example

`[ 398.936486] nvkm_ioctl+0x11d/0x280 [nouveau]
 ...
 [ 398.936486] RIP: 0033:0x7f89e40405d7
 ...
 [405.827360] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000000`

I've been following [this guide](https://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/) and am at the section titled "The Manual Boot".  First off, I cycled through all of the drives listed in the result set of the `grub> ls` command and none of them contains a `home/` directory.  However, one of them is labeled as being `UBUNTU` so I noted the UUID of that drive and hoped to proceed.

Unfortunately, when I tried to "tell GRUB where Linux is" I did not get the tab completion expected upon typing `linux /boot/vmlinuz< tab_here >` (no, I did not literally type "< tab_here >", I hit the tab key hoping for tab completion).

So I ran `ls /boot` hoping to find the vmlinuz file in question and just manually type it out.  There was no such file there.  If I had to guess, this is a big part of my problem.  But I have had no luck finding out what to do to fix this issue.

Can anybody help me out?

Note: I wiped the whole drive before installation. So macOS is no longer present. Only Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.

Comment: Oh by the way, I wiped the whole drive before installation.  So macOS is no longer present.  Only Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I kept digging and found [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).  I went the boot-repair GUI route rather than the terminal route.  The first time, I just ran the recommended repair.  No dice.

I tried a second time and customized the process a bit.  one of the settings allowed me to add the "nomodeset" bootarg which I had to do in order to get Ubuntu to install from the Live USB in the first place.  I think that setting is why boot-repair did indeed work the second time around.

I'm up and running now.  Phew!